# How to hide CommandUIHandler Command ribbon button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, ribbon

I have created a custom ribbon button for my list. For some pages I wanted to hide the ribbon button and for some pages I  wanted to disabled.
 I found how to make disabled, I wrote following code to make disabled.

```
 <CommandUIHandler Command="{A9424973-D302-4D7D-98B9-7489B6682780}" CommandAction="~site/SitePages/Test.aspx" 
                          EnabledScript="javascript:
    function isEnable(){
      if(location.href.indexOf('MyPage/DispForm.aspx') > 0){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    isEnable();"/>
```

My problem is how to hide ribbon button using `CommandUIHandler`. Anybody has an idea?

Comment: you are hiding it with commanduihandler, what do you expect?

Comment: This command makes it disable but didn't hide the button in ribbon. @Gwny

Comment: I wanted to hide my custom action anyhow for specific page/ or visible it for specific page

Comment: so your code does not work?

Comment: Above code is work only for disabling, I need a solution to hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: add another Custom Action with a Location set to where you want to hide it - for example attach it to list with a specific content type, or to a list based on a custom template (there are many different locations, just Google around):

```
<CustomAction
      Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
      RegistrationType="List"
      Sequence="10001"
      RegistrationId="10115">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="SET_THIS_TO_LOCATION_OF_YOUR_RIBBON_BUTTON" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

For example if you wanted to remove the original `New Item` button, you would set the `Location`  of `CommandUIDefinition`  to this: `Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem"`

Exclude the `CommandUIHandler` node from the XML completely and set `Sequence` number higher than on your other `CustomAction`. What will happen in this case - your original button will be added to the Ribbon and then your second `CustomAction` will overwrite it. Since the `CommandUIHandler` will be missing - the button will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use : [HideCustomAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ms414790.aspx) ??

With this, you can hide specific custom (the custom and OOTB CustomAction).